# Can gravitational waves be compared with a sinking water phenomena?

Tags: waves, gravity, speed-of-light, astronomy, gravitational-waves

Let's say we have some water in the sink and open the closure. The water starts to move towards it in a whirlpool-like manner. If we have a table tennis ball and leave it near the hole of the sink it will rotate like a planet instead move right towards the hole... If we suddenly open up more the hole the water will start to move faster toward the hole but even if the water moves towards the hole the orbiting ball will still be able to detect the change in the water speed due to the hole of the sink being opened more... Can this be compared with gravitational waves where even the spacetime tissue moves towards the BH binary star the orbiting planet is still in the position to detect this sudden perturbance moving in opposite direction regarding spacetime tissue similarly as the table tennis ball get the perturbance moving in the opposite direction than the water moving in direction of the sink hole?

Comment: Why do you think the ball will rotate and not move towards the sink? Unless the water isn't deep enough or the ball is too heavy it will just be drawn into the sink.